# How to remove a group of data if the last obs is less than certain value?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with some stock data, and am running into an issue with some aspects of cleansing my data.

Since I have data on most of the largest US equities, I want to get rid of all equities if

1. the price of the equity on the last day is less than $25 (just some made up #)

How would I go about coding this, preferably without having to use a for loop?

For example - lets say I have the dataset below:

```
Date       ID    EOD_Price  
2/1/10    AAPL    45.1
2/2/10    AAPL    45.3
2/3/10    AAPL    45.1   
 ...      ...     ...
2/1/10    JXL      2.6
2/2/10    JXL      2.5
2/3/10    JXL      2.8
 ...      ...      ...
2/1/10    RXW      26.5
2/2/10    RXW      25.9
2/3/10    RXW      24.9
```

... Essentially, my result would only include all of the data for AAPL since the price on the last date (2/3/10) is > 25.

Any idea on how to go about doing this?

the below code is something that I thought would yield the last obs for each stock, which then I can use in a for loop to subset maybe (im not too sure):

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% tail(EOD_Price, n=1)
```

but this only yields the last value for the last obs in the dataset.

Please advise. I just want to keep the ID's that are > $25 in price on the last day.

Thank you so much! Keep on learning!

Comment: Create a list of IDs that satisfy your condition. Then add a flag variable in your original dataset by checking if the ID is present in that list and then use subset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::last` you can select only stocks "IDs" were the last value is greater than 25

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(last(value)>25)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
  date   ID value
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 2/1/10 AAPL   45.1
2 2/2/10 AAPL   45.3
3 2/3/10 AAPL   45.1

#Another option is using n() instead of last, 
#where n() is number of rows (observatrions) in that group
df %>% group_by(stock) %>% filter(value[n()]>25)
```

## data

```
structure(list(date = c("2/1/10", "2/2/10", "2/3/10", "2/1/10", 
 "2/2/10", "2/3/10", "2/1/10", "2/2/10", "2/3/10"), ID = c("AAPL", 
 "AAPL", "AAPL", "JXL", "JXL", "JXL", "RXW", "RXW", "RXW"), value = c(45.1, 
 45.3, 45.1, 2.6, 2.5, 2.8, 26.5, 25.9, 24.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you. this was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
# Inner query: group by ID and check if EOD_Price>25 and 
#Outer query: select all rows which are belongs to the inner ID
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where ID in (select ID from df group by ID having EOD_Price>25)")
```

Output:

```
    Date   ID EOD_Price
1 2/1/10 AAPL      45.1
2 2/2/10 AAPL      45.3
3 2/3/10 AAPL      45.1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[last(value) > 25], by = ID]
#      ID   date value
#1: AAPL 2/1/10  45.1
#2: AAPL 2/2/10  45.3
#3: AAPL 2/3/10  45.1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2/1/10", "2/2/10", "2/3/10", "2/1/10", 
"2/2/10", "2/3/10", "2/1/10", "2/2/10", "2/3/10"), ID = c("AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "JXL", "JXL", "JXL", "RXW", "RXW", "RXW"), value = c(45.1, 
45.3, 45.1, 2.6, 2.5, 2.8, 26.5, 25.9, 24.9)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```